# How do I log a specific field in API requests within Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to cypress.log() out a specific field in the request header whenever my webapp makes requests that way when it fails and adds screenshots/logs I can grab that that requestId that failed.

Is there a way to setup cypress so that for all network requests it checks for this field and log it?

I can add a cy.intercept within each individual file but I want a more generic way to handle this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cypress.log](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cypress-log) is the synchronous version of `cy.log()`.

Add `middleware: true` to the intercept to pass request to other intercepts.

```js
cy.intercept({ url: '*', middleware: true }, (req) => {

  const headerValue = req.headers?['x-custom-headers']  

  if (headerValue) {
    Cypress.log({
      name: 'x-custom-header',
      message: headerValue
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you this helped! especially the part with the middleware and also showing how to use Cypress.log. I used a combination of this + the other answer with beforeEach.

Comment: Actually, you don't need `beforeEach()`. Once you set up `cy.intercept()`, it is effective for all tests.

Comment: Where would you add this cy.intercept() code snippet? To the support/index.ts?

Comment: I needed to add beforeEach because cy.intercept wasn't available without it. I added this to my support file. (also another note I ran into issues with using req.continue() so I removed that)

Comment: Ok, but be aware that each call to `cy.intercept()` adds a new one to the stack - they don't overwrite or remove old versions. Perhaps `before()` is better?

Comment: WRT `req.continue()` you are correct, it looks like it negates the `middleware` flag and sends the request off to the server without allowing other intercepts to see the request.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get an Cypress promise error if you try to use `cy.log()` to log out every request header in an `cy.intercept()` within a routeHandler callback. This would also make it kind of tough to log to a CI terminal as well.

Instead you can console.log to dev tools. To make it apply to all tests, you can wrap it in a `beforeEach()` and place it in the support/index.js file.

```js
// support/index.js

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept('*', (req) => {
      req.continue((res) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers))
      })
    })
})
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I didn't realize I could add beforeEach within the support files